# Troubleshooting a localStorage function

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I managed to get a code together that allows me to switch between different background images on the body of my website, and used localStorage to keep this change when going to a different page on the site. 
I tried to add in a bit of code that does the same for the colour of a #header class I defined in the CSS. It changes the colour, but does not keep the change, even though I'm using an identical method.

Javascript function to change colour:

```
function changeColor(bc) {
    var myElement = document.querySelector("#header");
    myElement.style.color = bc;
    localStorage['bc']=bc;
}
```

Switching colours:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('switchoff','','images/switchoffhl.jpg',1)" onclick="changeBg('url(images/woodback.png)');changeColor('#000');" 
        style="background-image:url('images/woodback.png')"><img src="images/switchoff.jpg" width="50" height="50" id="switchoff"></a>
```

CSS of header:

```
#header {
    padding:20px;   
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:36px;
    text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 0px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    clear:both;
}
```

Finally the function that keeps the background image constant, but doesn't do the same for the color:

```
(function () {
    if (!localStorage['bg']) localStorage['bg'] = "url(images/woodback.png)";
    document.body.style.background = localStorage['bg'];
    var myElement = document.querySelector("#header");
    if (!localStorage['bc']) localStorage['bc'] = "#FFF";
    myElement.style.color = localStorage['bc'];
})();
```

Can anyone spot anything I could have missed or got wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm understanding your posted code correctly, then you seem to using an identical key for the localstorage item you are referencing in the case of both the background-image and the color for the header.

Comment: I'm using 'bg' for the background image, and 'bc' for the header colour (granted not the most intuitive key) and I can't see any of them in the wrong place.

Comment: Please share the code for `changeBg` function